# Referencing a Dictionary

Tags: loops, dictionary, for-loop

I am trying to reference a dictionary but would like to print the second variable from that dictionary before the first. I've tried a few different ways, but am not having any success. This is my first post and am new to coding. Any help would be appreciated. Below is my code. I would like the email to display first. thank you!

```
contact_emails = {
    'Sue Reyn' : 's.reyn@email.com',
    'Mike Filt': 'mike.filt@bmail.com',
    'Nate Arty': 'narty042@nmail.com'
    }

for names in contact_emails:

print('%s is %s names', contact_emails[names])
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you marked it with `python` tag in case if it really is python.

Comment: sorry, it is Python. I will note that in the future. thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is python 3, you can use `.items()`:

```
for name, email in contact_emails.items():
    print('{} is {} names'.format(email, name))
```

Comment: That worked! And I can see why now, thanks for the help!